# Is it possible to show column instead of line in the "Visualization: Annotated Time Line" chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Here is a nice chart from google: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Example

**But is it possible to show column instead of line chart?**

Very important for me the zoomable option and the timeline on the bottom.

I know there is a column chart from google: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart but it's not zoomable as the "Visualization: Annotated Time Line"

Comment: The AnnotatedTimeline chart does not support columns, but you can use a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) to get the same functionality with a [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, we only support the line chart right now.